# How to manage panels docking in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, panel, docking

I am using Notepad++ recently I installed the Explorer plugin

But I can only find how to dock it on the left/right in tab with the other panels what I want is to dock it above the other panel so I can see the content of both at the same time

To clarify this is what I have:
[image]

But this is what I want: notice the difference in panel placement on the left
[image]

I know that i can put it on top/buttom/right of text area but that is not what I want

Comment: I'm with notepad++ v6.7.8.2 and I just installed Explorer plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the solution you are looking for, but I need the same thing, and this works for me.

Use any window you can dock there that you don't use (I use menu View->Document structure) and dock it to the location where you want your multi docked windows to be and resize it accordingly, then in undocked state, resize the panels and hover them above the panel that you placed there as placeholder.

Its not perfect, because you lose space due to the titlebar and if you move NP++ this undocked window will not move, but it is a workaround that in most cases will be useful enough.

For me, its NppFTP with Function List. Given that NppFTP also has an output window on the bottom, I have the docked window on the right side, so that I can actually overlap the non-used space of nppFTP's output window too! Win-win.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl + Alt + Shift + E (Or check the option Plugin>Explorer>Explorer)

I'm with notepad++ v6.7.8.2 and I just installed Explorer plugin and this shortcut dock the explorer in the left side of my notepad+9

[image: Notepad =++ Screenshot with Explorer on the left side et Explorer Options]

Comment: This I can do to but it is not what I want to make it  mor clear i have added photo-shoped pictures to the question

Comment: OK Jens, with your screenshot it's now clear for me. But i'm afraid it's not possible right now.

Comment: You can go to notepad++ forum to ask them directly (I'm interested by answer to this question too) : https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to redesign and rebuild the docking system, since it's an opensource editor, and the layout system is relatively simple, It won't take years to add such a feature.

Below is what I've achieved in a few hours:

[image: split panel]

https://github.com/KnIfER/Textrument (WIP)

description: while moving a floating panel or a preview window of a docked panel, holt **alt** to place it into the sub panel, or if the sub panel is already visible, you can simply drag and dock panels into it, just as usual.

Unlike that of MFC, Textrument's layout system doesn't allow you to split panels "infinitely". Split the original top and bottom panels horizontally, left and right vertically —— that's all, no further splits.

In my design, top and bottom panels have two extra properties  `Extrude Left`、`Extrude Right` which decide where to reside their left and right boundaries:

[image]

(Related code see [`DockingManager::reSizeTo`](https://github.com/KnIfER/Textrument/blob/875bdb58412eceb8438cdd3d357919d09311d792/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/DockingWnd/DockingManager.cpp#L446))